# How can you see all properties of a mail, calendar or task item in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

I'd like to see all the properties of any item in Outlook.  I know there are more properties than get exposed via the dialogs and forms within Outlook, but I don't know how to see behind-the-scenes.  For example, I'm sure a calendar entry must have a created date stamped on it.

Is there a tool or a secret keyboard shortcut in Outlook or something that lets you see a list of all properties and their values for a given item?  I'm thinking along the lines of ADSIEdit and how it can peek into an Active Directory domain and show everything.  Perhaps there is something similar for Outlook?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try out these two:

[Outlook Spy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/)

[MFCMAPI](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291794)

Answer (score 1):

For many items you can just choose the fields you want to show.
Your example of finding the date a calendar item was actually created is quite a common one, and is described in this article:
[Using Field Chooser to find out when an Outlook appointment was created](http://blog.meteorit.co.uk/2008/07/04/using-field-chooser-to-find-out-when-an-outlook-appointment-was-created/)